# Стоит ли читать книгу по django 2.1?

Tags: django

Хочу прочитать книгу В.Дронова по django (она версии 2.1),а версия django на данный момент 3.1
Стоит ли читать?(имею ввиду,что если прочитаю книгу по версии 2.1,те знания будут актуальны на версии 3.1?)

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.